# Tic Tac Toe school project getting very longwinded with if statements. Is a loop possible?

Tags: python

So for a school project we need to make Tic Tac Toe in Python. This is currently where i'm at. It semi works, yet without win detection. It is very long winded, and I am trying to condense all the if statements into loops, but I dont really know how to get it into a nice loop. Each if statement within the main function is ran depending on the input, which results in different items in the 2D list (board) being changed.

```
row1 = ["-","-","-"]
row2 = ["-","-","-"]
row3 = ["-","-","-"]

board = [row1, row2, row3]
rows = 3
for each in range(0,3):
    print(*board[each])

A1 = board[0][0] 
A2 = board[0][1]
A3 = board[0][2]
B1 = board[1][0]
B2 = board[1][1]
B3 = board[1][2]
C1 = board[2][0]
C2 = board[2][1]
C3 = board[2][2]

X = True 
game = True

def main(game, X):
    while game == True:

    if X == True:
        value = input("Position in Grid for X: ")
    if X == False:
        value = input("Position in Grid for O: ")

    if value == "A1":
        if X == True: 
            board[0][0]="X"
            X = False
        elif X == False:
            board[0][0]="O"
            X = True
        for each in range(0,3):
            print(*board[each]) 
        game = True
    if value == "A2":
        if X == True: 
            board[0][1]="X"
            X = False
        elif X == False:
            board[0][1]="O"
            X = True
        for each in range(0,3):
            print(*board[each])
        game = True
    if value == "A3":
        if X == True: 
            board[0][2]="X"
            X = False
        elif X == False:
            board[0][2]="O"
            X = True
        for each in range(0,3):
            print(*board[each])
        game = True
    if value == "B1":
        if X == True: 
            board[1][0]="X"
            X = False
        elif X == False:
            board[1][0]="O"
            X = True
        for each in range(0,3):
            print(*board[each])
            game = True
    if value == "B2":
        if X == True: 
            board[1][1]="X"
            X = False
        elif X == False:
            board[1][1]="O"
            X = True
        for each in range(0,3):
            print(*board[each])
            game = True
    if value == "B3":
        if X == True: 
            board[1][2]="X"
            X = False
        elif X == False:
            board[1][2]="O"
            X = True
        for each in range(0,3):
            print(*board[each])
            game = True
    if value == "C1":
        if X == True: 
            board[2][0]="X"
            X = False
        elif X == False:
            board[2][0]="O"
            X = True
        for each in range(0,3):
            print(*board[each])
            game = True
    if value == "C2":
        if X == True: 
            board[2][1]="X"
            X = False
        elif X == False:
            board[2][1]="O"
            X = True
        for each in range(0,3):
            print(*board[each])
            game = True
    if value == "C3":
        if X == True: 
            board[2][2]="X"
            X = False
        elif X == False:
            board[2][2]="O"
            X = True
        for each in range(0,3):
            print(*board[each])
            game = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Your control loops aren't properly indented beneath `while game == True` right at the start of your `main` method. Try fixing that to see if the game works then?

EDIT:

If you want to shorten, you could try using a dictionary to map your grid like follows. I modified your code a bit. As for win conditions etc., you should be able to add further conditionals for those.

```
X = True 
game = True

def main(game, X):
    #Initialize the gameboard.
    row1 = ["-","-","-"]
    row2 = ["-","-","-"]
    row3 = ["-","-","-"]
    board = [row1, row2, row3]

    for each in range(0,3):
        print(*board[each])

    table = {'A1': board[0][0], 'A2': board[0][1], 'A3': board[0][2],
             'B1': board[1][0], 'B2': board[1][1], 'B3': board[1][2],
             'C1': board[2][0], 'C2': board[2][1], 'C3': board[2][2]}

    while game == True:

        if X == True:
            value = input("Position in Grid for X: ")
        if X == False:
            value = input("Position in Grid for O: ")

        if value in table.keys():
            if X == True: 
                table[value]="X"
                X = False
            elif X == False:
                table[value]="O"
                X = True

            rows = list(table.values())
            board = [rows[0:3],rows[3:6],rows[6:9]]

            for each in range(0,3):
                print(*board[each]) 
                game = True
```

There are still problems with overwriting positions etc., but you only have one main `if elif` loop to worry about now when generating player moves. Good luck!

Comment: That was an error with my formatting here, they are properly indented in the actual program. It works fine, but i just want to see if i can shorten it into a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use functions, at least one that converts an input to a tuple of indices (row and column).

This function should split the input into two characters. The letter can then be converted to the row, the digit to column. These conversions can be done independently and with a few tricks (using `ord()` on the letter and `int()` on the digit plus some math) very short. The function then returns an index tuple to use on `board`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to shorten this code is to get a method to turn a string, like `"B3"` into the corresponding indices of the 2D array, `[1][2]`.

The method can look like this:

```
def indices_of_string(s):
    letters = ["A", "B", "C"]
    numbers = ["1", "2", "3"]
    return (letters.index(s[0]), numbers.index(s[1]))
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
(x, y) = indices_of_string(value)
if X == True: 
    board[x][y]="X"
    X = False
elif X == False:
    board[x][y]="O"
    X = True
for each in range(0,3):
    print(*board[each]) 
game = True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten your code by applying the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle. In this case not only are you using a lot of `if` statements, they're also all very similar. If you analyse what the differences are, you can often generalize what going on by adding or computing variables that can then be used in place of hardcoded literal values like `"A1"` and `[0][1]`.

I've partially done this to your code, and ended-up with the following. You could easily take it a little further by create a `display_board()` function and calling it instead of repeating the `for each in range(0, 3):` loop in more than one place.

```
row1 = ["-","-","-"]
row2 = ["-","-","-"]
row3 = ["-","-","-"]

board = [row1, row2, row3]
rows = 3
for each in range(0, 3):
    print(*board[each])

X = True
game = True

def main(game, X):
    while game == True:

        if X == True:
            value = input("Position in Grid for X: ")
        if X == False:
            value = input("Position in Grid for O: ")

        ## Convert two-letter value string to integer column and row indices.
        col, row = ord(value[0])-ord("A"), int(value[1])-1

        if X == True:
            board[col][row]="X"
            X = False
        elif X == False:
            board[col][row]="O"
            X = True

        for each in range(0, 3):
            print(*board[each])

main(game, X)
```

**Note** Both this and your code are infinite-loops because nothing ever sets `game = False`. I assume you'll eventually add something that checks and determines if the game is over and which player, if any, won.